# i setup a virtual host on ubuntu with a real website url and now i want to access the real website how to?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I think the title explained my question but here it's simpler:

virtual host: www.something.com
real website: www.something.com

when i type www.something.com in the address bar my browser always send me to the local virtual host how to go to the real website without deleting my virtual host or disable it.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.  You can change your /etc/hosts file on your machine so that http://www.something.com points to the real host by putting an entry in like the below.  Replacing 192.168.111.111 with the real IP.

`192.168.111.111     www.something.com     something.com`

The better approach would be to change the name of your local virtual host to be something like http://www.devel-something.com so you have two distinct sites.